# Is there a way to verify if an email address is a valid PayPal email?

Tags: paypal

Before registration is completed on my mobile app, I want to check whether the person who comes to register has a PayPal account or not, without doing a payment.

Comment: Before complete the register procedure. I want to make sure the person done the registration having a paypal account

Comment: No, you can't do it

Answer (score 1):

You can implement [Connect with PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/connect-with-paypal/) for them to sign in. You'll only get a response from users who have (or created) an account for the sign-in